# pyodbc.connect works in script, fails as part of Flask API

Tags: sql-server, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I've created a simple Flask API that reads/writes to a JSON file, but I would like to replace the JSON storage with a SQL Server database. I am currently developing a test version on my local machine before putting it on a production server. My python\SQL connection works perfectly when it is a standalone script being called from the console. However, once I call the same connection method from a Flask app, I get a pyodbc.InterfaceError.

I wrote a simple script that uses the following connection string:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
                      Server='localhost',
                      Database='<db_name>',
                      Trusted_Connection='yes')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table')
```

The script does some parsing with the return data from the SELECT statement and successfully prints the data as a string when I run this sample script in the console.

However, when I run that same code as a GET in my Flask app, I get the following error:

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:
(traceback info...)
conn = pyodbc.connect(.....
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user '<domain>\\<pc-name>$'.(18456)(SQLDriverConnect); ...")
```

I don't understand why the same connection string wouldn't work depending on where its being called from. Is there something going on behind the scenes in a Flask application that would cause an incompatibility with pyodbc? Or with a particular syntax? I have done a lot of troubleshooting and found that the Flask app works fine until the pyodbc.connect is called.

Comment: `Trusted_Connection='yes'` indicates that it should be using Active Directory/Kerberos/Windows Authentication to authenticate with the SQL Server, meaning that it using the authentication token of the current process. i.e.: Since your web application is running in the context of the `<domain>\\<pc-name>$` user those are the details it is using to attempt to authenticate with SQL Server. Do you have a Windows Logon created for the `<domain>\\<pc-name>$` account on your production SQL Server?

Comment: Also, since the error message includes error number 18456 have you tried to  connect to the target server with SSMS to see what the Error Logs have to say about the matter? Via the Server-Instance node > Management > SQL Server Logs look for the 18456 error events, take note of their `State` numbers and compare them against those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16) to see why SQL Server thinks the connections are unsuccessful.